# How to Override the Sales Order Quick Process Action Button in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to override the Quick Process Action Button in Acumatica.

Requirement:
After clicking on the OK Button, print pick list and the Shipment confirmation should be opened as a Combined in a single report instead of opening in the two separate tabs.

We could not able to locate the Quick Process action button.

Please help me to resolve this .

Answer (score 0):

Quick Action button is made available, per order type.  Review the Sales Order type screen.

Inside the standard graph SalesOrderEntry graph, you will find the method QuickProcess.  It is available after you create the graph extension.  Inside your extension, you may extend QuickProcess.  Or override if you wish.

[image]